# Channel Audio from .mp4?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, audio, mp4

I am at a loss here after searching around with no results.

I am attempting to channel the audio specifically from an .mp4 for use in a driver.

I am aware that there are programs which extract the audio from .mp4's, but I am looking for another approach without using external applications such as those.. is there any direction that someone can point me towards to solve this problem?

Thanks,

-K

Answer (score 0):

The open source library libavcodec, which is part of ffmpeg has the capability to do what you are looking for. The source is available at [link text](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html).